# DocuSign template - multiple recipient roles sign on different sign tabs

Tags: docusignapi

I have a DocuSign template `template-1` with multiple recipient roles say `signerrole-1` and `signerrole-2.`

Template-1 has multiple signature tabs, viz, signtab-1 & signtab-2.

Using REST API, I am trying to create the envelope so signerrole-1 signs signtab-1 and signerrole-2 signs signtab-2.

I am not clear on how to associate signerrole-1 role and signerrole-2 role to signtab-1 and signtab-2 respectively using api java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template associates roles with tabs (fields) in the document(s).

When you create the template, you create signature tabs for the specific roles. It is easiest to do this by using the Web interface to DocuSign but you can also do this using the Create Template API call.

Later, when you submit a new envelope using the template, you associate specific people or signing groups with the roles defined by the template. [See this recipe for an example.](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/request-a-signature-via-email-using-a-template)

When you create the envelope to be sent, you do *not* create or reference the signing tabs. They are defined by the template.